# Attached ENI trunk to custom security group in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I recently enabled ENI trunking feature in ECS. An extra ENI interface is created and attached to the default security group.

Cloudformation (ec2 launch template) is use to launch the ec2 instance. How do I attached that extra ENI trunk interface with custom security group in launch template? The groups assign in network interface doesn't take effect.

```
ECSAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: MyECSAutoScalingGroup
      VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref Subnets
      MixedInstancesPolicy:
        LaunchTemplate:
          LaunchTemplateSpecification:
            LaunchTemplateId: !Ref ECSLaunchTemplate
            Version: !GetAtt ECSLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      MinSize: !Ref ClusterSize
      MaxSize: !Ref ClusterMaxSize
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref DesiredSize

  ECSLaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: MyECSLaunchTemplate
      LaunchTemplateData: 
        KeyName: MyKey
        ImageId: !Ref ImageId
        InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SecurityGroup
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: !GetAtt ECSInstanceProfile.Arn
        NetworkInterfaces:
          - AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
            DeviceIndex: 1
            Groups:
              - !Ref SecurityGroup
```

Comment: A CFN template demonstrating your problem would be helpful. Thus, please add it to your question.

Comment: I have update to attach the CFN template

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported by ECS. It's in the feature request but no ETA on when it will be released.
So the best workaround would be to restrict default security group to the same rule set as your custom security group.